# Android emulator window borders are not synced

Tags: android, android-emulator

If you take a look at this screenshot you can notice that the screen and the window frame are not in sync.

[image]

This is causing the lot of trouble clicking on emulator.

The click works when clicked in the frame but not on the actual place of the screen.

How do I fix this?

I've tried creating new emulators but it hasn't helped me getting away with this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I found a workaround.

For anybody facing this issue - just scale the window on the fly.

Here's how you do it:

Open up telnet client and type in the following commands in the order

```
telnet localhost PortNumOfAVD
window scale 175dpi
quit
```

Voila! now this should work. Please adjust the dpi settings to your screen and convenience.

For those on windows and don't see telnet client? Please follow the link to enable telnet client in Windows
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-the-telnet-client-in-windows-10/